# Making an image be behind divs so divs scroll over images

Tags: html, css

I am sorry for phrasing this poorly. Don't really know how to explain it but I have images of what I want to achieve.

I want to learn how to implement stuff like this

[image]

[image]

I don't fully understand the css behind it and don't know what to google on. I've been looking up stuff on parallax ads but I cant find this behaviour explained anywhere. If anyone has some resources I can read I'd appreciate it a lot. I understand the background image has to have a lower z-index than rest of content on a site, but the rest I dont fully grasp.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: `z-index` is all you need...

Comment: Here is something that could maybe get you started - https://codepen.io/brumgb/pen/GRJBeNP

Answer (score -1):

Just Need to make the image `position:absolute;` and `z-index:-10;` or more depends on if you are using z-index in any case.it will take the image out of the html flow. now you can write the html as you would normally do.it would stay in the background..

```css
div{
height:100px;
width:100px;
outline:1px solid red;
color:white;
}
img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:-10;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1663832669528-df3f45bce473?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
<div>Div 4</div>
<div>Div 5</div>
<div>Div 6</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, its almost what I want. What I want is essentially an image in its own div. So let's say the image is in div 2, and div 1 and div 3 can overlap it as you scroll, and then maybe div 4 and div 6 can scroll over div 5. I hope I'm making sense

Comment: yes in that case the css i put inside the `img{}` will go on that `div` instead